# org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist in select statement by createQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, exception

Group and rule have One to Many bidirectional relationship. When I call getSingleResult method on entityManager, I got PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist : Rule

Query is :

```
entityManager.createQuery("select t from Template t join t.batchContacts bc 
join t.groups g where t.enabled = 1 and t.eventType.id=:eventTypeId and 
t.media=:media and bc.code =:contactCode and "
+ "g.id =:groupId and t.codes is null");
```

stack trace :

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.tosan.chapar.core.entity.Rule
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
Wrapped by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.tosan.chapar.core.entity.Rule
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:307) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at com.tosan.chapar.core.persistence.jpa.TemplateDaoJpa.getTemplate(TemplateDaoJpa.java:262) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.tosan.chapar.core.service.impl.TemplateServiceImpl.findEnableGroupAndBatchTemplate(TemplateServiceImpl.java:280) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.tosan.chapar.core.service.impl.TemplateServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2a5066e2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
```

I read similar question and try to debug. but I still could not find out why I get that exception and how can Isolve it. I need something to demystify for me why i got that, and how to solve with minimum side effect, because those entities uses different places in my project and I don't have time to test all scenarios.

Comment: You get that exception because, in order for this query to return the things you expect, Hibernate needs to flush all the changes made in memory before executing the query. This causes persist operations to occur during the flush, and since you're trying to persist a detached entity somehow, you get that exception. So the problem is not the query. It's the code executed before executing the query. As always, the exception stack trace would confirm that, but as always, it's not in the question...

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. I updated my question. added stack trace.

Comment: The stack trace confirms everything I said in the previous comment. The problem is in the code you execute before executing that query.

Comment: @JBNizet i checked methods, they don't change state of objects. they only select objetc. so why when hibernate flushes. I should got Exception got exception ?

Comment: They do make changes. You missed something. I can't say what, since I can't see anything of your code.

Comment: @JBNizet I did double check. In a method, transaction commit and so my object detach. I set Transaction annotation on upper level method. but still problem exists. methods that named in stack traced have a native Query for just select, not change. stack trace shows me there is a problem in there, but I don't understand what and why.

Comment: Can you add code how you are building Rule entity before persisting... problem lies there .....

Comment: @Hamid .. How did you solve this problem?

Comment: @securecurve I think the right was with JBNizet.

Comment: @Hamid, so, How did you change your code in order to make it work. Thanks!